# Getting all users in ArcGIS Online organization?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api, administration

I want to return a list of all users in my ArcGIS Online (AGOL) organization. However, the result returned in `gis.users.search()` [appears limited to 100 users](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/considerations-and-limitations.htm).

Is there any way to return all users or to perform multiple searches until all users are found?

Answer (score 4):

Try using the [UserManager](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#usermanager) with the Python API. The UserManager has an option for max_records which can be set to the number of users in your group

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import arcgis 

gis = GIS("https://www.arcgis.com", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD") # set first arguement to your Portal or AGOL
users = arcgis.gis.UserManager(gis)

# get the total number of users in your AGOL account provided you have administrative priveledges
totalUsers = users.counts('user_type', as_df=False)[0]['count']

# use the total number of users in your AGOL Account as an arguement for max_users
allUsers = users.search(query=None, max_users=totalUsers)
```

Comment: ArcGIS Enterprise 10.6.1 returns "NotImplementedError: `counts` is not implemented at version 6.1 of Enterprise" - is there a workaround?

Comment: @wunderkind I updated my answer so that it even simpler than before. But in regards to Enterprise. I don't have access to Enterprise but the docs https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#usermanager
Still list "counts" for Enterprise or AGOL

Comment: @F_Kellner - please email me: khibma@esri.ca - I have something to help.

Answer (score 1):

Go download the free Admin tools from GeoJobe available in the ArcGIS online store. Believe it creates an Excel output

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue but was able to fix it using a loop

```
def get_users_info(gis,esriplatform):
    start = 0
    users_info = []


    while True:
        source_users = gis.users.advanced_search(query='!esri_ & !portaladmin', start=start, max_users=200)
        list_users = source_users.get('results')

        if not list_users:
            break

        users_info.extend(list_users)
        start += 100

    return users_info
```

Answer (score -1):

While it's true that each individual query returns a max of 100 records, you can use pagination to send multiple requests for up to 10000 results.

https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/search.htm - see the `start` and `num` parameters.